# Range of a function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I already have the Domain part but I need the range, what is the range? The function is $f(x)=-2x^2+5$ and the domain is $(-3,3].$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MVeb.jpg

Comment: New here.  All the trouble you went through to change your username, after deleting **this very same question** at a point in which you had already earned 4 downvotes? Or did you create a new account altogether to try to erase any trace?

Comment: @amWhy Let's give OP a chance to solve the problem.  I helped them with part of it and gave a hint for the second part.

Comment: @user46944 You provided no more information to the OP than was provided him/her in comments to this same question, which has since been deleted.  S/he was told about graphing, informed how to read a graph...etc.

Comment: @amWhy But OP is engaging in the comments with me.  I want to help them understand.

Comment: I will delete my account after solving this question sorry if I created an issue here in the page, but to be honest I find this new answer better explained at my level, that's all I'm gonna say and thanks for trying to help me before.

Comment: @Newhere Feel free to ask me questions in the comment of my answer if you have any trouble moving forward with the problem. :) Also, don't let this experience bring you down.  This site is filled with people who like to help others with their math problems.  I hope you'll give this site another chance in the future.

Comment: @user46944  You clearly don't know me, because I've spent all of my time here at MSE helping users at all levels.  What I find frustrating is when users try to get around rules, expectations etc, by deleting a question, and reposting it...

Comment: @amWhy I understand your point.  And I believe that you have the best interest of the site at heart -- just look at your reputation!  But please consider making an exception in this case.  OP is making an effort to understand the problem.

Comment: Listen I understand that, I really didn't mean to cause all of this and is my fault, as you can see I'm new on the page and I didn't know about rules or anything like that at first, it was my mistake, do not take it with @user46944 and forgive me.

Comment: Newhere  I'm not angry with @user46944. And I empathize with your situation.  Of course I forgive you!  And you are more than welcome to continue working with the site and learning, etc.  You might want to take a little time over the next day or two, to [read the tour of the MSE site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour).  So we'll simply call this situation here, now, a learning opportunity.

Comment: Thank you very much for understanding, I will make sure to take my time and read it, greetings.

Comment: New here  One more thing: no need to delete your account!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a picture of the graph.  Do you know how to graph it yourself?  If not, you should review it.

The range is the values on the $y$-axis that have a piece of the function to the right or left of them.  Can you tell what the range is from the picture?

[image]

Comment: So the domain is not (-3,3]?

Comment: @Newhere Did the problem state "Find the domain of $f(x) = -2x^{2} + 5$"?  If so, then $(-3,3]$ is not the domain. :)

Comment: It is just asking me to descibe the domain and rangem it already gives me the domain, then ask you for the inequality, set notation and interval notation which I already have.

Comment: @Newhere Oh, ok.  So if it already gives you the domain, then you don't need to find it.  Let me update my answer with a picture of the graph which has domain $(-3,3]$, and from there you will be able to see what the range should be.  (It's not $(-\infty, 5]$ like I said earlier.)

Comment: @Newhere You're welcome.  I updated my answer with a picture.  Please let me know what you think the correct answer is.

Comment: I might be wrong but I had to draw a table with the values and I get that the range must be [-13,5]

Comment: Is infinite isn't it? I guess it just keeps going

Comment: Then it should be -4

Comment: Thanks, now sorry if I keep bothering you I'm just in doubt, our teacher made a table on the board givin us x and y. it was like this, x had the values of -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3 and y only had -13, it was for us to complete it, does this somehow goes with the answer you help me find?

Comment: @Newhere Do you have any way of taking a picture of the homework problem and uploading it to your question description?

Comment: @Newhere By the way, I'll be away from the computer for about half an hour.  Hope that's ok.

Comment: Is totally fine, I was doing the work so it might be wrong in the paper but I will try to upload it.

Comment: Actually, $[-13, 5]$ is correct in this case with $f(x) = -2x^2 +5$. The greatest value in the range is $5$ (when x = 0), and the least value of f(x), given the domain, is when $x=3$: because $-2(3^2)+5 = -18+5 = -13$. I think the graph is off.

Comment: [See this graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)%3D-2x%5E2%2B5) of $f(x)= -2x^2 + 5$. The lower graph shows the given domain. Note the y-values at $x = \pm 3$

Comment: user46944: Please attend to your graph, because it is not and cannot be the graph of $f(x) = -2x^2+ 5$. It is actually the graph of $f(x) = -x^2+5\neq -2x^2 + 5$.  The OP (New here) was correct in his/her work and solution that the range is indeed $[-13, 5]$.

Comment: Oh I see, Thank you both user46944 and @amWhy for your help!

Comment: @Newhere I think you know/knew more than you gave yourself credit for! Be proud of yourself for your solution, having used a table you created, from which you found the correct range: $[-13, 5]$.  Trust your abilities to tackle these kinds of question! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @amWhy I will look forwards to improve my math skills and thank you as wll for your patience with me!

Comment: @amWhy Leave it to me to mess up my graph and probably confuse the heck out of poor New here.

Comment: I've been there!  It happens to us all!  I'd just go through your exchange of comments with the OP to delete comments base on your initial graph, (e.g. "@Newhere The 5 is correct but the −13 isn't. Take a look at the graph I have in my answer. Look at the y-axis values. Which y-axis values have a piece of the function directly to the right or left of them?" ) , and the one affirming to the OP that$-4$ is the lower bound of the range...

Comment: That's all, just so as to leave the answer helpful in case future users are searching for "domain and range" related questions to serve as examples.

Comment: @amWhy Good idea, just did that.

Comment: Nice job, user46944!